# C# declare delegate signature from existing function

Tags: c#, delegates

I would like to avoid declaring the function signature twice for a delegate when I already have the function sitting there in the code. I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I can't seem to find how to do this by googling.

```
public class SomeLibraryV1
{
  public int DoSomething(int x, int y);
}

public class SomeLibraryV2
{
  public int DoSomething(int x, int y);
}

public class SomeConsumer
{
  // Create the delegate by manually declaring the signature again :-(
  private delegate int DoSthDelegate(int x, int y);

  public void Run(DoSthDelegate aDelegate)
  {
    aDelegate(1, 2);
  }
}
```

So what I'd like to do is just avoid the second declaration of `int fn(int, int)`. Something like

```
public class SomeConsumer
{
  // Create the delegate from the function signature we already know :-)
  public delegate DoSthDelegate(SomeLibrary.DoSomething);

  public void Run(DoSthDelegate aDelegate)
  {
    aDelegate(1, 2);
  }
}
```

This would not only save me typing every single declaration twice but would save me having to maintain things in two places should the signature of `DoSomething` change.

Comment: Take a Func<int,int,int>?

Comment: OK and how do I get that from the declaration of SomeLibrary.DoSomething?

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I don't know a way to do this (before run time). I guess you have to be explicit here. The ```Func<>``` may save you some typing, though.

Comment: Oh well, you could do code generation using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx but I don't know if that helps in your case.

Comment: I have no idea what you're actually trying to do. Your question isn't making much sense. Why should any specific existing method serve as a prototype for a delegate type? If you really don't want to declare a new type, why don't you just use `Func<int, int, int>` (as proposed above)? You can't do literally what you're asking for, but if you could explain why you think this is useful and/or what _specific_ problem you think it solves, you might get a useful answer.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap a C DLL interface with a C# class which can either use 'static' binding with `DllImport` which will search the executable's directory and system paths for the DLL or 'dynamic' binding with `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` to a path to the DLL specified by the user, so that the wrapper(s) may support loading multiple versions of the same DLL. Thus I have `[DllImport("SomeLibrary.dll")] public static extern int DoSomething(int x, int y);` written out in the file and would simply like to use that function declaration as the basis for the delegates I marshal.

Comment: I think the question is fairly simple - why can't an existing function define the signature for a delegate? There would be lots of situations where not having to declare the signature multiple times for a function that is *right there in the same code file* would be handy. WinForms GUIs where you want to invoke functions would be a classic example.

Answer (score 0):

You´re missing an assential - not to say the important point - on delegates. You can register *any* method with the same signature. Thus it´s not really helpful to bind your delegate to just one fix method. If you´re only invoking the same method, than you shouldn´t use a delegate at all. Simply call your `DoSomething`-method directly in your `Run`-method instead of invoking the delegate:

```
Run()
{
    var retVal = DoSomething(3, 5)
}
```

In fact a delegate is nothing but a signature which may be satisified by multiple methods as well. Moreover that´s the basis for events where you can register multiple event-handlers via the same delegate-definition.

So all a delegate does it to indicate that there is a method that expects two int-values and returns an int. However it doesn´t make any assumption on where this method is defined - it might also be an anonymous one, e.g.:

```
Run((x, y) => x + y);
```

Of course this is some duplicated typing. However it ensures that you can´t invoke a method that doesn´t fit the delegates signature. So the only thing you can do is to use the `Func`-delegate instead of creating your own one:

```
public TheFunc Func<int, int, int> { get; set; }
```

You can set this via this statement:

```
Run(instanceOfMyLibrary.DoSomething);
```

or also:

```
Func<int, int, int> f = instanceOfyLibrary.DoSomething;
Run(f);
```

NB: Your delegate must be `public` in order to provide it as parameter to your `Run`-method.

Comment: Yeah obviously I have an actual reason to use delegates, I just kept the example brief. Do you have an answer to the question? How can I create TheFunc from the signature of SomeLibrary.DoSomething?

Comment: I'm talking about the declaration of the delegate, now how to call it...

Comment: Imagine you didn´t want to execute `DoSomething`, but `SomethingDifferent`. The point of delegates is to be able to call both - either `DoSomething` or `SomethingDifferent` as they *both* satisfy the signature. Binding a delegate to a fix method would make the delegate complety useless. Having said this you *have* to define the delegates signature *explicitely*.

Comment: What does "FFS" mean?

Comment: "Feeling Frustrated Sorry" ;-)

Comment: Yes, and DoSomething and SomethingDifferent would have the same signature. So *either* of them would be a place where I could get the *declaration* of the delegate from. I know how to call a function!

Comment: So you want to create a delegate from a template?

Comment: But I can´t imagine what you want to do with that delegate. You´d have to assign any method to it to use it in any way. Even if you *could* create a delegate from a template, how would you use it as it´s just the **declaration** of your delegate. So all you get is `Func<int, int, int>`, but you have to assign some method to that delegate.

Comment: Give up dude. I know why I'm using a delegate and what they're for. If you "can't imagine what I want to do with that delegate" then you're clearly not going to be able to answer a question about declaring one. You're not going to get upvoted for repeatedly explaining what a delegate is.